# Casting double (not a pointer) to void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Is it legal to cast this way?

```
void probability(void **value)
{
    double v = 0.1234;
    *value = (void *) *(uint64_t *) &v;
}
```

I know, this is a bad thing, but I'm 100% sure that `sizeof(double)` = `sizeof(void *)` = `sizeof(uint64_t)` on target machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's undefined behavior, because your code violates the strict aliasing rules.

The compiler is permitted to assume that pointers to most unrelated types don't point to the same memory. You create a `uint64_t *` (the result of the cast) that points to memory which is "actually" a double, and you expect reading from that pointer to give you a value that has something to do with the double.

The purpose of the strict aliasing rules is to allow the compiler to make various optimizations that will break this code - the most likely is that the compiler can "deduce" that `v` is unused and never initialize it, since it's never accessed via any *valid* name or pointer, only invalid aliases.

I haven't checked with this specific code, but GCC does in fact rely on strict aliasing at high optimization, and will break this sort of code.

The way to fix strict aliasing problems is with `memcpy`:

```
assert(sizeof(*value) == sizeof(v));
memcpy(value, &v, sizeof(*value));
```

Once this is done, or if you're using a compiler that doesn't rely on strict aliasing, or for which that reliance can be avoided (`--no-strict-aliasing`), then you still have a problem. The standard doesn't actually guarantee that every numeric value of the same size as an address, can actually be represented in `void*`. For example, it's legal for the implementation to (in effect) have padding bits in pointers, and to crash if you try to create a pointer value with the wrong values in the padding bits. In practice that isn't going to happen on any hardware that you'd call "normal", but nevertheless the standard doesn't permit your code.

Comment: Is there a "true" way to store double in void pointer? I can not refactor part of the code that use void* as its storage for everything and I can not malloc storage for doubles since it will very inefficient (abot 1M allocations).

Comment: @actual: no, there isn't. It is not guaranteed that there are at least as many distinct legal values of `void*` as there are distinct values of `double`, even if the sizes make it look as though there should be.

Comment: Perhaps you could do a single allocation of `sizeof(double)*1000000`, store the values in that array, and store a `double*` in the `void*`. Free the array when you're finished with all of them. This probably takes twice as much memory as doing what you want, but shouldn't be all that much slower.

Comment: @actual Unless it's been changed between n1570 and the ratification, you can use a union. 6.5.2.3, fn 95: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation."

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, maybe I will use some kind of linear allocator. Thank you for an enlightenment.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: To be strict, or not to be strict, that is the question ;)

Comment: @actual For non-strictness, use Haskell. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, no. The part

```
*(uint64_t*)&v;
```

is undefined behaviour. The cast of the `uint64_t` to `void*` is legal but may be meaningless, such casts are implementation defined (6.3.2.3).

Comment: Point 7 of section 6.3.2.3 seems to say pointers to different object types (i.e. not functions) can be cast to each other.  The behaviour is only undefined if the cast results in an incorrectly aligned pointer.

Comment: Yes, I referred to point 5, conversion of integers to pointers. The undefined behaviour comes from the dereferencing, which violates the strict aliasing rules, cf. Steve Jessop's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior. Not matter how sure you are.

Comment: I know this is true in C++ but is it true in C as well? Do you have a reference from the C99 standard?